# Google Chrome 78 won't load secure sites

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, osx-el-capitan

I just upgraded to version 78 of Google Chrome (OSX 10.11.6 El Capitan) and now all websites which use SSL will not load.

On screen I get a "This site can't be reached ERR_FAILED" error without any other explanation.

Running Chrome with logging enabled (`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --enable-logging --v=1`) I get this:

```
[3412:18179:1028/192953.776220:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_mac.cc(76)] Unknown error mapped to ERR_FAILED: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=100005 "EIO: Input/output error" (100005)
[3412:11267:1028/192953.776490:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(969)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -2
```

Anyone experiencing this?
Thanks!

Comment: If you downgrade Chrome to an earlier version what happens?  Have you tried using Chrome with a new user profile?  `ERR_FAILED` is basically an "unknown error", there is no specific cause for the error, so additional details will have to be collected.

Comment: Yes, just downloaded version 76 from https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php and everything works as expected... :/

Comment: Issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1024000 This also hit Chrome 79 on MacOS 10.10/10.11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complete uninstall did the trick... Remove Google Chrome app and delete all content from "~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome"